# How to change the media volume to max and then to previous value after playing some sound in android java?

Tags: java, android, media

I am making an app that plays some sound in maximum media volume. After playing the sound i want to make the media volume back to the previous user set value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save current index of AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC before playing sound.

```
 AudioManager amanager2 = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

 int currentindex= amanager2.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

//it will return the current volume index for the stream.
```

After playing sound, you can set index of AudioManager to `currentindex`.

```
amanager2.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, currentindex, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

Hope it helps!